# Phrase or saying to mean proceeding from a point of inspiration

Tags: phrase-requests

I was typing a comment and couldn't word it correctly, or rather, couldn't remember the phrasing one would normally use for that situation. So I stated, 'I was going with the "godly" part' (*as my inspiration**); meaning I felt that the adjective *godly,* in the OP's example sentence, was a significant part of the context and that I should proceed from there (to search for a short phrase having that connotation, allusion, etc.).

While clicking on synonyms, I did find the word *brainwave.* It hasn't helped.

- *I was going with that.*
- *I was running with that.*
- *I took it from there.*
- *I expounded...* (No, it's not detailing.)
- *I expanded...* (On one word?)
- *I focused on "godly" and went from there.* (That lacks *inspiration.*)
- jump-started, springboarded (Too much...energy.)

---

Update (18 March 2021)

I found an example sentence that conveys what I'm trying to say, very well, but it's in a different context (a group setting; plural imperative), and I would prefer a phrase that encompasses that meaning, if possible. (Source: Macmillan Dictionary, under [run with it](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/run-with-it).)

> Let’s pick up this idea and run with it.

*The phrase *as my inspiration* was not part of the original comment or this question; it was added for clarity to both later (March 11th and 18th, respectively).

---

Maybe I'm searching for jargon, but I don't think so. It could be embarrassingly simple; it happens. In any case, I've searched for hours and can't find it.

BTW, this is just a question about an actual comment I made concerning a quest tale, nothing more. (Full context, under [*harrowed souls*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/562249/whats-good-wording-for-souls-of-people-who-died-of-injustice/562351#562351), 2nd to last answer.)

Comment: Took off from there? Launched? Rocketed?

Comment: I was riffing on *godly*?   I was triggering on...  I was going off of ...  I was basing it on ...

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you are asking, or ask it a different way? Maybe provide the whole comment you typed, for context. I am having trouble understanding what you're looking for. A synonym for . . . ?

Comment: *Brainstorm*? [To try to solve a problem or come up with new ideas by having a discussion that includes all members of a group...](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brainstorm). *We brainstormed on "godly" for our party theme.*

Comment: Is it something like, "Influenced by the godly intervention, I went ahead with...."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made "godly" my **cornerstone** and built upon it.

"Godly" was my **cornerstone** and I built upon it.

Answer (score 1):

*Took as my inspiration...* And if not then perhaps you should have.

Answer (score 1):

“...and went from there” is clear and concise. I think it is in the right place. Adding unnecessary drama rarely produces better writing.

Answer (score 1):

*starting point* may sometimes be useful. Here is a text and a comment:

When I first read *godly** I felt unable to answer because of the complexity of your thought. Reading it again, I now appreciate the emphasis that you place on the commenting rather than the example text.

**godly* was my **starting point** for a train of unproductive quasi-theological thought that led me through a speculative trail of notions that eventually proved to be quite irrelevant to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some more ideas, just in case:

*...and I winged it from there*

*...and I improvised*

*...and I gave it a whirl*

*...and I went with that*

Answer (score 1):

Godly was my:

- inspiration
- hypothesis
- starting point
- foundation

You often hear people today talk about "standing on the shoulders of giants." This is meant to say that your ideas are built on top of many brilliant people before you and, without them, you wouldn't have been able to do what you have done. You might work this in since it's popular right now, IDK.